# valid provisioning profile not found

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, provisioning-profile

Whenever I try to test my current app with Xcode Instruments, two identical messages pop up:

[image]

This only happens when I use instruments. A previous version of the app has already been accepted by the app store and I just sent another version to Apple for review, without any complaints about profiles.

This isn't a showstopper as I can dismiss the alerts and use Instruments anyway but it is quite annoying.

Anyone any idea what could be causing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the profiling, using Instruments, needs to be done in the Release configuration, using an Ad-hoc provisioning profile. You're seeing that message probably because the device you're trying to use for Instruments is not in the provisioning profile you're using.

So you would have to enter the iOS Developer portal, add your device to the provisioning profile, reinstall the provisioning profile. Then that message shouldn't appear again!

Comment: So it has to be Ad-hoc? I had no idea. Thank you.